# Vim is hang after type dot with autocomplete in ruby file

Tags: vim

Vim are hanging after I type *dot* in cmd variable in ruby file.

[image]

I try this, but didn't work:

```
let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 0
```

My vimrc are here: https://github.com/niltonvasques/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/vimrc

The results of strace log in vim process is this:

```
stat("/home/niltonvasques/.vim/bundle/vim-ragtag/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", 0x7ffc2cfe3ba0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/niltonvasques/.vim/bundle/vim-surround/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", 0x7ffc2cfe3ba0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", 0x7ffc2cfe3ba0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23554, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23554, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23554, ...}) = 0
open(".", O_RDONLY)                     = 6
fchdir(6)                               = 0
chdir("/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload")  = 0
getcwd("/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload", 4096) = 30
fchdir(6)                               = 0
close(6)                                = 0
stat("/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23554, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", O_RDONLY) = 6

fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23554, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f815d471000
lseek(6, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(6, "\" Vim completion script\n\" Langua"..., 4096) = 4096
stat("/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/rubycomplete.vim", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23554, ...}) = 0
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(6, [0 3 5], NULL, [0 3], {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
read(6, "9@:\\-()\\.]\\+...\\?\\|lambda\\|&\\)'\n"..., 4096) = 4096
read(6, "lready completed?' )\" % name )\n "..., 4096) = 4096
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(6, [0 3 5], NULL, [0 3], {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
read(6, "$:.index( rails_lib )\n\n    bootf"..., 4096) = 4096
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(6, [0 3 5], NULL, [0 3], {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
read(6, "plete_buffer_loading\")\n    if lo"..., 4096) = 4096
read(6, "Range.instance_methods(true)\n\n  "..., 4096) = 3074
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(6, [0 3 5], NULL, [0 3], {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, {0x7f815a2c15f0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8150505000
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={2, 16126}, ru_stime={0, 180011}, ...}) = 0
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 9  
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f8159df5180}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {0x7f815a262270, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f815a7928d0}, {0x5255d0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f815a7928d0}, 8) = 0    
getegid()                               = 1000
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10264, ...}) = 0
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10264, ...}) = 0
close(12)                               = 0
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 12
read(12, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\7\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10264, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105408, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 12, 0) = 0x7f8150302000
mprotect(0x7f8150304000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f8150503000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 12, 0x1000) = 0x7f8150503000
close(12)                               = 0
mprotect(0x7f8150503000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
brk(0x2ab2000)                          = 0x2ab2000
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14328, ...}) = 0
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14328, ...}) = 0
close(12)                               = 0
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 12
read(12, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\6\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14328, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109472, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 12, 0) = 0x7f81500fe000
mprotect(0x7f8150100000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f8150300000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 12, 0x2000) = 0x7f8150300000
close(12)                               = 0
mprotect(0x7f8150300000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
brk(0x2ad3000)                          = 0x2ad3000
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34951, ...}) = 0
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34951, ...}) = 0
close(12)                               = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34951, ...}) = 0
ioctl(12, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7ffc2cfe0db0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34951, ...}) = 0
read(12, "# -*- ruby -*-\n#--\n# Copyright 2"..., 8192) = 8192
read(12, "ame+.  If the +exec_name+\n  # is"..., 8192) = 8192
read(12, "hen it inserts the activated gem"..., 8192) = 8192
read(12, "latform.match p\n    }.sort_by { "..., 8192) = 8192
read(12, "r.join ':'}:Warning: \" \\\n    \"Rb"..., 8192) = 2183
read(12, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(12)                               = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34951, ...}) = 0
brk(0x2af4000)                          = 0x2af4000
brk(0x2b15000)                          = 0x2b15000
brk(0x2b36000)                          = 0x2b36000
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems/defaults.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3098, ...}) = 0
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3098, ...}) = 0
close(12)                               = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3098, ...}) = 0
ioctl(12, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7ffc2cfe0830) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3098, ...}) = 0
read(12, "module Gem\n\n  # TODO: move this "..., 8192) = 3098
read(12, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(12)                               = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3098, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9991, ...}) = 0
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9991, ...}) = 0
close(12)                               = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9991, ...}) = 0
ioctl(12, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7ffc2cfe0830) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9991, ...}) = 0
read(12, "\n# This file was created by mkco"..., 8192) = 8192
brk(0x2b5a000)                          = 0x2b5a000
read(12, "NFIG[\"libexecdir\"] = \"$(prefix)/"..., 8192) = 1799
read(12, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(12)                               = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9991, ...}) = 0
brk(0x2b81000)                          = 0x2b81000
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/deprecate.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems/deprecate.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/deprecate.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/deprecate.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1851, ...}) = 0
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1851, ...}) = 0
close(12)                               = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1851, ...}) = 0
ioctl(12, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7ffc2cfe0830) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1851, ...}) = 0
read(12, "##\n# Provides a single method +d"..., 8192) = 1851
read(12, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(12)                               = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1851, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/exceptions.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems/exceptions.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/exceptions.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/exceptions.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2393, ...}) = 0
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2393, ...}) = 0
close(12)                               = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2393, ...}) = 0
ioctl(12, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7ffc2cfe0830) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2393, ...}) = 0
read(12, "##\n# Base exception class for Ru"..., 8192) = 2393
read(12, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(12)                               = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2393, ...}) = 0
brk(0x2ba3000)                          = 0x2ba3000
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/ruby.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/ruby.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems/defaults/ruby.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/ruby.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/ruby.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/ruby.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/ruby.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/ruby.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/ruby.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/ruby.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems/defaults/ruby.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/ruby.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/ruby.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/ruby.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/ruby.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/defaults/ruby.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/custom_require.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/rubygems/custom_require.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rubygems/custom_require.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/custom_require.rb", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1871, ...}) = 0
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1871, ...}) = 0
close(12)                               = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
open("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb", O_RDONLY) = 12
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1871, ...}) = 0
ioctl(12, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7ffc2cfe0830) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1871, ...}) = 0
read(12, "#--\n# Copyright 2006 by Chad Fow"..., 8192) = 1871
read(12, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(12)                               = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1871, ...}) = 0
brk(0x2bc4000)                          = 0x2bc4000
brk(0x2be6000)                          = 0x2be6000
brk(0x2c07000)                          = 0x2c07000
brk(0x2c2b000)                          = 0x2c2b000
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f815d471000, 4096)            = 0
brk(0x2c52000)                          = 0x2c52000
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(5, 0x1e78d14, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(6, [0 3 5], NULL, [0 3], {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
brk(0x2c91000)                          = 0x2c91000
read(0, "a", 8192)                      = 1
read(0, "\33", 8192)                    = 1
read(0, "k", 8192)                      = 1
read(0,
```

Comment: One of your plugins is misbehaving. Narrow it down and then ask about the specific plugin(s). (Side note: `let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py'`, you should not be using this `.ycm_extra_conf.py` as your `.ycm_extra_conf`. You should write your own that is tailored to your project. This one is tailored to ycmd and is not a general purpose one.)

Comment: The hangs only stops if I remove `filetype plugin on`. I remove sample ycm conf, but this don't help fix the hang, because I think that are only used for c++ files.

Comment: The ycm comment probably has nothing to do with the problem. Anyways, Why do you think `let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 0` would solve your problem, you don't appear to be using python-mode. You are editing a ruby file, I don't think python-mode applies. You have like 10-15 plugins in your bundle directory. Do any of them apply to ruby? Can you try dialing your plugins and finding out which ones are necessary to cause the problem? `filetype plugin on` allows filetype detection to work so ruby files load ruby ftplugins.